Any reason to keep this question open for 6 days?
I am not a regular visitor and I only visit here from time to time to study Chinese. I saw the linked question, we teach eachother ，I teach you chinese，you teach me other language！ 6 days ago and flagged it as off-topic. 
I just wonder if there is any reason that I am not aware of to keep this question open here. Based on my experience on other SE sites, this question doesn't seem to be appropriate for Chinese Stack Exchange.  

There were not enough votes to close the question. Now it's closed.
